# unknown column in 'on clause' with multiple group_concats

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that I'm trying to join on `e.id`--both queries individually work fine but when I combine into one I'm running into `Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'e.id' in 'on clause'` error.

Here are the individual queries which work as expected:
(e.* includes e.id)

```
SELECT e.*, a.authId,
                   a.firstName,
                   a.lastName,
                   a.affiliation,
                   a.location,
                   a.imageUrl,
                   a.slug as profileSlug,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(b.attachmentUrl SEPARATOR '----') as attachmentsUrlList
                FROM Experiments e
                LEFT JOIN Accounts a ON e.authId = a.authId
                LEFT JOIN Attachments b on e.id = b.attachableId AND b.attachable = 'experiments'
                WHERE e.deletedAt IS NULL
                GROUP BY COALESCE(e.id);
```

and query two is:

```
SELECT e.id,
                   CONCAT(
                      '[',
                      GROUP_CONCAT(
                      if(d.taggableId is null,"",
                        JSON_OBJECT(
                          'type', c.type,
                          'value', c.value
                        ))
                      ),
                      ']'
                    ) AS tagList
                FROM Experiments e
                LEFT JOIN Taggings d ON e.id = d.taggableId AND d.taggable = 'experiments'
                LEFT JOIN Tags c ON d.tagId = c.id
                WHERE e.deletedAt IS NULL
                GROUP BY COALESCE(e.id);
```

I'm trying to join them together using this JOIN:

```
SELECT e.* FROM (

                   SELECT e.id, a.authId,
                   a.firstName,
                   a.lastName,
                   a.affiliation,
                   a.location,
                   a.imageUrl,
                   a.slug as profileSlug,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(b.attachmentUrl SEPARATOR '----') as attachmentsUrlList
                FROM Experiments e
                LEFT JOIN Accounts a ON e.authId = a.authId
                LEFT JOIN Attachments b on e.id = b.attachableId AND b.attachable = 'experiments'
                WHERE e.deletedAt IS NULL
                GROUP BY COALESCE(e.id)
                ) as e

inner join
(SELECT e.id,
                   CONCAT(
                      '[',
                      GROUP_CONCAT(
                      if(d.taggableId is null,"",
                        JSON_OBJECT(
                          'type', c.type,
                          'value', c.value
                        ))
                      ),
                      ']'
                    ) AS tagList
                FROM Experiments e
                LEFT JOIN Taggings d ON e.id = d.taggableId AND d.taggable = 'experiments'
                LEFT JOIN Tags c ON d.tagId = c.id
                WHERE e.deletedAt IS NULL
                GROUP BY COALESCE(e.id)) as b
                on e.id = b.id;
```

This query should work, not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: *I'm running into unknown column in 'on clause' error.* Show complete and unchanged error message text.

Comment: `COALESCE(e.id)` makes no sense and is equal to `e.id`. The function arguments amount must be 2 or more.